# Show tree 'lines' in WPF

Tags: wpf, treeview

I have a treeView in WPF in which I have several level. When I expands the level, I would like to display dotted lines from the parent to the leaves so that it's more visual. However, it doesn't to be like that by default.

Is it possible, and if yes, how?

Thanks you.